# How do I test for a mob, with a given name, in a certain location?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to testfor a sheep, by the name of Lamb, in a certain location using coordinates.

I have already tried this:

```
testfor @e[x=999,y=80,z=-1034,type=Sheep,name=Lamb]
```

But it doesn't work. I have also tried:

```
testfor @e[x=999,y=80,z=-1034,type=Sheep]
```

But it says it found a sheep whether or not there is actually a sheep in that location.

Comment: Whatever it is you're doing, you probably don't want to be using `testfor`.  `testfor` isn't completely useless in 1.9, but there's often better alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `x`, `y`, and `z` parameters only change the origin of the search. To check for targets within a certain range of that origin, you will need to use selection limiters like `r` (radius, number of blocks in each direction from the origin to find a target):

```
/testfor @e[x=999,y=80,z=-1034,r=1,type=Sheep,name=Lamb]
```

Comment: I tried using that command as well but the output claims that it is an unknown command.

Comment: @Themadtadder Ensure your command block is being activated correctly. If you're using a comparator clock, the signal closer to the comparator only reduces in signal strength rather than turning off. You'd need to increase the distance between the comparator and command block.

Comment: Currently I am using a repeater to power the command block. The repeater that is powering the command block is also connected to a repeater clock. The block is activating correctly because I first put in a "say" command, to test if the command is being activated, and it says the message.

Comment: @Themadtadder I can't currently check, but if I recall correctly, a selector that has the **possibility** of targeting multiple entities but found none will result in no error message at all (and in pre-1.9, the last output will not change from what it was prior). You'll also have to ensure that there is a sheep named "Lamb" within 1 block of those coordinates.

Comment: I am terribly sorry Skylinerw, your command worked perfectly. The problem that ran into was that the sheep that i was trying to find did not have the name capitalized.